# Issue with SharePoint List not showing all content in one column (rich text)

Tags: list, content, missing

I am having issues with SharePoint List. It is not showing all the content on my SharePoint page. Is there a code I can use to increase the height? It is rich text and from what I have read, it is not possible but this seems like a simple issue that has not been resolved for many months.

I see it all good on SharePoint List but when I embed on SharePoint page it is all trunckated.